# Scifi novel about an interstellar ship that encounters an alien ship

Tags: story-identification, novel

This (softcover) book was about a slow interstellar colony ship

- They couldn't find a planet to settle as it had been passed by later
  faster ships.
- They crash into an alien spacecraft.
- The hero is a woman with a robotic arm

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with more details. We have prompts [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). For example, when did you read it? What language? Physical or ebook? You can [edit] more details in as they come to mind. And don't forget to visit the [tour] so you know how to accept an answer.

Comment: :) Good details to [edit] in. I take it that after they were [leapfrogged](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog), they decided to keep going, and that's where they ran into the other vessel?